# Docker Node backend - "this site can't be reached"

Tags: node.js, docker, deployment, apollo-server

I'm trying do build a docker image of my Node backend for deployment but when I run it in a container and open in the browser I get "This site can’t be reached" error and the following log in dev tools:

> crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated

My backend is based on GraphQL Apollo server. Dockerfile is as following:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --only=production
# RUN npm install

COPY . .

# RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 4000


CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

I've also tried to use the commented code, with no result.
The image builds without a problem and after running the container I get   `Server ready at localhost:4000` in the docker logs, so I'd expect it to work properly.

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"start": "node dist/main.js",
"dev": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"nodemon dist/main.js\""
```

},

That's the scripts part of my package.json I've also tried CMD ["npm", "start"] in Dockerfile but that doesn't work either. When I run the backend from terminal using npm start I can access the GraphQL playground at localhost:4000 - I assume that should be the same with docker?

I'm still new to docker so I'd be grateful for any hints. Thanks

EDIT:
I run the container with the following command:
docker run --rm -d -p 4000:80 image-name:latest

Seemingly it's running on port 0.0.0.0:4000 as that's what it says under 'PORT' when I execute docker ps

Comment: What's the command with which you run the docker itself?

Comment: What is the actual code running inside the container?  In general, if a process in a container is only listening on `localhost`, it won't be reachable from outside its container, and you need to configure it to listen on the special `0.0.0.0` "all interfaces" address.

Comment: @MichaelOstrovsky I've just edited the post to address the comment

Comment: If the service inside the container is listening on port 4000, that needs to be the second `docker run -p` port number as well; maybe `docker run -p 4000:4000`.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you, that seems to have been a problem. Could you do me a favour and elaborate on the behaviour, that'd be appreciated?

Answer (score -1):

Please run docker inspect command and you will get IP and then run through that ip in browser

Comment: That IP address isn't usable except on one very specific host configuration, and it's never necessary to look it up.